# Spreadsheet Data Not Refreshing Prior to Running Google Script

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet which imports stock prices from google finance & other sources, then calculates port folio value.
There is also script which saves daily valuation data.
This has been running well for nearly 2 years, but since early May, it seems to be saving the same data every day, like it's not refreshing the stock prices.

Of course, if I open it manually and run the script, it all works OK.
If I don't open the sheet, the script now saves unrefreshed stock prices.   What's the best way to force a refresh ?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trigger` function in your `app script`, where trigger to run your `script function` daily, hourly and it is one of the most powerful feature in Apps script, far better and easily to set-up compared to RPA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My script runs at the time intended, but as described in my opening post, the data it collects is no longer refreshed.

Comment: In such case, you need write a scrip to scrap price and save it somewhere, it work no issue. This issue is that your price is using `importXml`, which will not refreshing if your never open it.

Comment: The problem is with both google finance and importXml functions.   All worked OK for many months until early May.    I am trying it with the addition of SpreadsheetApp.flush().    Looks promising so far.